# Limits of dbms_sql

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I'm using a package (found on https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/as_xlsx20.txt) which gets in input a SQL string and generates on output an XLSX in BLOB format.
If I pass as parameter a SQL where one of the column is larger than 2000 characters, I get nothing and I've noticed that in the package it's used the DBMS_SQL and by taking a look to Oracle specification I see that among the parameters there is "TYPE varchar2_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000)". Does it mean that DBMS_SQL can't manage more than 2000 characters for every column? I'm trying to understand why when more that 2000 chr extracted, the package dosn't work and I'm guessing why since the package is very complecated and there's no "2000" constant string inside.

Oracle version 10g

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Comment: That code has an `exception when others` catch-all that is hiding whatever is actually erroring. If you add a `raise` in there then it might give you some idea of what is actually wrong. You may still to need some debugging info to the package but that would be a starting point.

Comment: The `dbms_sql` package itself has no limits on the lengths of strings it can retrieve.  This particular library might well have limits, you'd potentially need to debug it to see.